# How to install aws iot greengrass on windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, mqtt, aws-iot-greengrass

We are using .net core windows form application(client).
Mqtt protocol used for communication between client & server.
Need to install greengrass in windows machine(server). So need to pass data from server(greengrass) to aws iot core.

So how to install greengrass on windows 10

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the AWS docs?

Comment: yes. read with the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v1/developerguide/install-ggc.html . but it doesn't contains installation in windows.

Comment: Also read with this document. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v1/developerguide/run-gg-in-docker-container.html . Is aws greengrass installed via docker container?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you can only run Greengrass in Docker container.
But if the only thing you need is MQTT message exchange between your app and AWS IoT Core, you don't need Greengrass at all. I'd even say Greengreass would complicate things more.

Instead write MQTT client extension for your app and it will publish and subscribe directly to AWS IoT Core.

Here you have sample .Net MQTT publisher/subscriber application:

https://github.com/aws-samples/iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer

If you want to built in more functionality here is .NET SDK API reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

### Update:

On 12th November 2021 AWS released Greengrass version 2.5.0 which can be installed on Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10 devices.

Some Greengrass features may still not be supported though.

For current requirements and limitations refer to the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/setting-up.html#greengrass-v2-supported-platforms

Happy coding!